# SQL Server log file autoshrink

Tags: sql-server, database-design

My database is in simple recovery model, I'm not expecting exponential growth of log file, however log file size is becoming large.

Is autoshrink a good solution?

Will autoshrink affect application performance in simple recovery mode? Is 50GB threshold a good threshold?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "becoming large"? The log size in the `SIMPLE` recovery model will reflect the space you need for ongoing operations so you shouldn't shrink if it's only going to grow again (which will reduce performance). If you had a one-time operation that cause the log size to increase and it will not happen again, then perform a one-time shrink to reclaim the space.

Comment: The log file size has grown again to almost 200GB, even after SQL admin has shrunk it. I understand from your comment that auto shrink may affect performance, is there any other way to limit log file size? BTW the application is writing thousands of transactions per minute.

Comment: My comment was mostly about autogrow impacting performance, which will be the result after autoshrink when more space is needed. The log is growing for a reason. What does `SELECT log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases` show?

Comment: Yes, you can limit the size of the log file. But when that limit is reached, your database will stop operating and need an admin to shrink the file. Since "autoshrink" does what it says, there must be a reason for the large size. With thousands of transactions per minute, that size might be needed. If these transactions do have any value for your company, you should probably not use the simple recovery model but increase disk space instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment:

> The log file size has grown again to almost 200GB

I can suppose that your database is not a good candidate for `autoshrink` (and speaking from my practice it's a rare case when `autoshrink` is good solution for 
db).

#### Recommendations

1. Make initial size of log file(s) **big enough**. It's a trial and error process just look that free space exists and not too large. Never shrink log files to zero free space.
2. Make increment size of log not %-based but constant size. By default SQLServer has a %-based size increment. Make this increment **big enough**. Again it's a trial and error process.
3. Check that filesystem(s) where log file(s) are placed have enough free space. You don't want fragmented log files and you absolutely do not want database outage under peak workloads.
4. Last but not the least. Check open transactions when your log file is unexpectedly big. I will expand this topic below.

#### DBCC OPENTRAN

If log is big and cannot be shrinked - it means that you have a lot of data in open transactions.

Check it with [DBCC OPENTRAN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-opentran-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Look carefully.

You can find the culprits - programs/clients that open transactions, make a lot of modifications and then never `commit`s/`rollback`s them.

Keep in mind that log is growing linearly and one "bad" transaction can prevent log space reuse (and shrinking too)

Find such culprits, find programmers/users who open such transactions, as last measure - **kill** them.

Clarification:

> I mean `kill` as in T-SQL [kill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/kill-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

I have strong suspicion that not-closed transactions are your case.

Inform about your progress.

Good luck!